# Обновить файлы .properties во время выполнения программы Java

Tags: java

На сколько я понимаю, то файлы `.properties` читаются на этапе компиляции, собираются в проекте. И все что бы ты в них не менял изменения уже не подтянутся.

Задача следующая: После того как я авторизуюсь на сайт, я получаю список `ID`, для дальнейшего использования. Получаю документ следующего вида:

```
Custom = 0
Container = 1
Home_Page = 4
les = 6
Sold_History = 7
```

и использую потом поиск в файле `.properties`

```
Integer.parseInt(PropertyLoader.loadProperty(PropertySource.WIDGETSID, "Home_Page"))
```

Как мне во время выполнения программы обновить `.properties` иили есть какой то другой вариант?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это веб приложение?

Comment: Да это веб приложение.

Comment: а почему не хотите хранить в памяти? например в servlet context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/index.html) умеет делать это, см. [Automatic Reloading of Configuration Sources](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_reloading.html)